# Spring MVC What other values can be added to @initBinder, besided bean names?

Tags: java, validation, spring-mvc

Can you set for the `value` of `@InitBinder` something beside the bean name, in spring mvc?
For instance, the method names?

Comment: Could you be more explicit in your question ? According to Javadoc, `@InitBinder` annotates methods (in controllers).

Comment: probably I was not specific enough - I was referring to the values that can be passed for annotation - I upated my question. And I read the documentation - it is not clear enough for the aspect that I am interested in.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can only put the name of a bean as parameter of the `@InitBinder` annotation. **But** you can allways use a different bean name in each controller method, thanks to the `@ModelAttribute ("bean_name")` annotation. That way you can configure your `WebDataBinder` for each method.

Comment: long story short, the bean name must be identical in both methods.